# Scroll to element in Zepto (or jQuery) only when off screen

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, zepto

So, I've got a list of items, and it is longer than the height of my browser window:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="2">Item 2</li>
    ...
    <li id="99">Item 99</li>
</ul>
```

I know how to scroll to an item:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#99').offset().top
},
'fast');
```

In my app, a background process is updating list items (for example, a list of downloads that are completing). I want to show the update on screen, but **I only want to scroll there if it isn't currently visible** (instead of constantly scrolling each item to the top)...

I don't really care (right now) if the item is scrolled to the top, or to the middle, or if the screen is moved a page at a time. I assume it will be easiest to scroll to the top.

For example

```
---------------------------
|Downloads:               | no progress
| Item 1                  |
| Item 2                  |
| Item 3                  |
| Item 4                  |
| Item 5                 v|
---------------------------

---------------------------
|Downloads:               | Item 3 downloaded - no scroll
| Item 1 - downloaded     |
| Item 2                  |
| Item 3 - downloaded     |
| Item 4 - downloaded     |
| Item 5                 v|
---------------------------

---------------------------
| Item 6 - downloaded    ^| Item 6 downloaded - scroll element to top
| Item 7                  |
| Item 8                  |
| Item 9                  |
| Item 10                 |
| Item 11                v|
---------------------------
```

Can anyone please shed some light on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bd8sQ/). It's not exactly what you asked as I used container and subelement, and not checking that element is visible on the screen - only within container. But the idea should be clear.

You have to calculate current active element position and compare it with visible area offset/size:

```
if(element.position().top < 0){
    container.scrollTop(container.scrollTop() + element.position().top);
} else if(element.position().top + element.outerHeight() > container.height()) {
    container.scrollTop(container.scrollTop() + parseInt(element.position().top) + element.outerHeight() - container.height());
}
```

I've used container and element.position() for calculation. Container should have `position:absolute/relative` for correct `.position()` calculation. Otherwise position will be calculated relative to document element. In your case you probably will use `offset()` for position calculation relative to document regardless of parent `position` style.